# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in thymeleaf template

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have been trying to pass a list of object which contains products details through on button click. But I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" for the list of object.

```
<button type="button" th:onclick="'javascript:addProductFields(' + ${status.index} + ', ' + ${status1.index} + ',' + ${dailySaleHistoryDto.productList} +')'" class="btn btn-info"> +</button>
```

My guess is there is something wrong with the syntax for passing reference "dailySaleHistoryDto.productList".

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems which I notice in this example:

1) dailySaleHistoryDto.productList

As you mention in your question, this may be a problem (or it may not be). If the productList is actually a Java `List` object, then you may not get the results you expect - Thymeleaf will convert this to a string in your template. If the object is a list of strings, then you will get something that looks like a string representation of an array:

```
[item1, item2, ...]
```

This may, or may not, be a problem - it depends on what you need to do with the data. For example, you can convert it back from a string into an array in JavaScript.

2) The "onclick" JavaScript

You will need to use Thymeleaf's `[[...]]` [inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) notation for embedding Thymeleaf variables into JavaScript. I would recommend moving the JavaScript into its own section - for example, in your document's header. So, something like this:

```
<head>
...
  <script th:inline="javascript">
    function addProductFields() {
      var status = [[${status.index}]];
      var status1 = [[${status1.index}]];
      var dailySaleHistoryDto = [[${dailySaleHistoryDto.productList}]];
      // show that it worked - print the values to the browser console:
      console.log(status);
      console.log(status1);
      console.log(dailySaleHistoryDto);
      // whatever logic you need goes here...
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Then, you can simplify your button to this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addProductFields();" class="btn btn-info"> +</button>
```

Note that you no longer need to use `th:onclick` - just `onclick`. You have moved all the variables to a separate script (in this example).

This may not get you all the way to a complete solution, because of point (1), but it should help.